# Postgres connection taking 5 seconds to establish remotely

Tags: postgresql, database-connection

I have two servers on the same network, one hosting a PostgreSQL database, and the other hosting a webserver.

Connecting to the PSQL database locally via localhost or the IP is instant.
Ping from the DB server to the webserver is <1ms,
Ping from the webserver to the DB server is <1ms.
Connecting to the PSQL databse remotely via the IP from the webserver takes 5 seconds every time.

However, after connection, all transactions are fast.

Here are the logs showing the difference between a local connection and a remote connection.

```
LOCAL connection
2017-06-14 16:09:02 UTC [21966-171] DEBUG:  forked new backend, pid=22322 socket=12
2017-06-14 16:09:02 UTC [22322-1] postgres@postgres DEBUG:  postgres child[22322]: starting with (
2017-06-14 16:09:02 UTC [22322-2] postgres@postgres DEBUG:      postgres
2017-06-14 16:09:02 UTC [22322-3] postgres@postgres DEBUG:  )
2017-06-14 16:09:02 UTC [22322-4] postgres@postgres DEBUG:  InitPostgres
2017-06-14 16:09:02 UTC [22322-5] postgres@postgres DEBUG:  my backend ID is 12
2017-06-14 16:09:02 UTC [22322-6] postgres@postgres DEBUG:  StartTransaction
2017-06-14 16:09:02 UTC [22322-7] postgres@postgres DEBUG:  name: unnamed; blockState:       DEFAULT; state: INPROGR, xid/subid/cid: 0/1/0, nestlvl: 1, children:
2017-06-14 16:09:02 UTC [22322-8] postgres@postgres DEBUG:  CommitTransaction
2017-06-14 16:09:02 UTC [22322-9] postgres@postgres DEBUG:  name: unnamed; blockState:       STARTED; state: INPROGR, xid/subid/cid: 0/1/0, nestlvl: 1, children:




REMOTE CONNECTION

================= connection attempted on clientside ====================
2017-06-14 16:07:18 UTC [21966-147] DEBUG:  forked new backend, pid=22256 socket=12
2017-06-14 16:07:18 UTC [22256-1] [unknown]@[unknown] DEBUG:  SSL connection from "(anonymous)"
2017-06-14 16:07:18 UTC [22256-2] webserver@maindb DEBUG:  postgres child[22256]: starting with (
2017-06-14 16:07:18 UTC [22256-3] webserver@maindb DEBUG:   postgres
2017-06-14 16:07:18 UTC [22256-4] webserver@maindb DEBUG:  )
2017-06-14 16:07:18 UTC [22256-5] webserver@maindb DEBUG:  InitPostgres
2017-06-14 16:07:18 UTC [22256-6] webserver@maindb DEBUG:  my backend ID is 2
2017-06-14 16:07:18 UTC [22256-7] webserver@maindb DEBUG:  StartTransaction
2017-06-14 16:07:18 UTC [22256-8] webserver@maindb DEBUG:  name: unnamed; blockState:       DEFAULT; state: INPROGR, xid/subid/cid: 0/1/0, nestlvl: 1, children:
================== connection established on clientside  ======================
2017-06-14 16:07:23 UTC [22015-51] webserver@maindb DEBUG:  shmem_exit(0): 1 before_shmem_exit callbacks to make
2017-06-14 16:07:23 UTC [22015-52] webserver@maindb DEBUG:  shmem_exit(0): 6 on_shmem_exit callbacks to make
2017-06-14 16:07:23 UTC [22015-53] webserver@maindb DEBUG:  proc_exit(0): 3 callbacks to make
2017-06-14 16:07:23 UTC [22015-54] webserver@maindb DEBUG:  SSL: write alert (0x0100)
2017-06-14 16:07:23 UTC [22015-55] webserver@maindb DEBUG:  exit(0)
2017-06-14 16:07:23 UTC [22015-56] webserver@maindb DEBUG:  shmem_exit(-1): 0 before_shmem_exit callbacks to make
2017-06-14 16:07:23 UTC [22015-57] webserver@maindb DEBUG:  shmem_exit(-1): 0 on_shmem_exit callbacks to make
2017-06-14 16:07:23 UTC [22015-58] webserver@maindb DEBUG:  proc_exit(-1): 0 callbacks to make
2017-06-14 16:07:23 UTC [21966-148] DEBUG:  forked new backend, pid=22257 socket=12
2017-06-14 16:07:23 UTC [21966-149] DEBUG:  reaping dead processes
2017-06-14 16:07:23 UTC [21966-150] DEBUG:  server process (PID 22015) exited with exit code 0
2017-06-14 16:07:23 UTC [22257-1] [unknown]@[unknown] DEBUG:  SSL connection from "(anonymous)"
2017-06-14 16:07:23 UTC [22257-2] webserver@maindb DEBUG:  postgres child[22257]: starting with (
2017-06-14 16:07:23 UTC [22257-3] webserver@maindb DEBUG:   postgres
2017-06-14 16:07:23 UTC [22257-4] webserver@maindb DEBUG:  )
2017-06-14 16:07:23 UTC [22257-5] webserver@maindb DEBUG:  InitPostgres
2017-06-14 16:07:23 UTC [22257-6] webserver@maindb DEBUG:  my backend ID is 7
2017-06-14 16:07:23 UTC [22257-7] webserver@maindb DEBUG:  StartTransaction
2017-06-14 16:07:23 UTC [22257-8] webserver@maindb DEBUG:  name: unnamed; blockState:       DEFAULT; state: INPROGR, xid/subid/cid: 0/1/0, nestlvl: 1, children:
```

Just to be clear, the issue happens with SSL mode off as well.

Comment: Check your DNS.

Comment: If you have lots of clients you might want to install pg_bounce https://pgbouncer.github.io/

Comment: There are no more log entries for process 22256? What authentication method is used? Does it make a difference if you connect to the database using the IP address rather than the host name? Do you see an improvement if `log_hostname = off`?

Comment: If you're desperate, you can boot up wireshark to capture and inspect what's happening on the wire and when, frame by frame, the entire traffic your client sent and received. Even without peeking through SSL you might be able to spot who's waiting for what, for how long.

Comment: To your question add as text 1) The Web server and version. 2) The connection code the Web server is using. 3) What happened between [22256-8] and [22015-51]?

Comment: Still smells like DNS to me. What is the DNS response? Is there any chance it's doing some sort of load-balancing? e.g. 5 seconds sounds reasonable for "try to connect to server A, it's not there, give up, connect to server B" Have you looked at any strace output? e.g. if I do "strace --absolute-timestamps --follow-forks psql --host 192.168.0.123" I see a 3 second pause whilst it tries to figure out that 192.168.0.123 isn't routable.